# How can I kill a child process without the child process 'exit' event triggering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm spawning a child process:

```
child = spawn("childprocess", [], {
    detached: true
}
```

And I'm watching the 'exit' event with:

```
child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    // Do stuff
}
```

When my app exits, I'm killing the child by using `taskkill` (because this is running on Windows):

```
exec(`taskkill /PID ${child.pid} /F /T`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    // Do stuff
}
```

The problem is, that when the process is killed the exit event fires (understandably), but I don't want it to. Is there some way to remove the event listener? Or kill the process without triggering events? I've tried `child.removeListener('exit')` but that didn't work (maybe because it's an anonymous function?).

Comment: Maybe you can use IPC and ask for there process to terminate itself

Comment: @Vitim.us, well I hadn't thought of that. Not ideal, but if it comes down to it I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried `child.removeListener('exit')` but that didn't work (maybe because it's an anonymous function?).

Whether the function has a name or not doesn't matter. You simply need to pass the same function object to `removeListener` (or `off`):

```
var handler = (code, signal) => {};
child.on('exit', handler);
child.off('exit', handler);
```

Or call [`child.removeAllListeners('exit');`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname).